# Custom Meta Data - Hacking security

Tags: security, custom-metadata, encryption

Is it secure to set as custom meta data, for example, Credit card details or any other sensitive data?
Is there any existing option to encrypt this data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it secure to set as custom meta data, for example, Credit card details or any other sensitive data?

No. Custom Metadata records, other than those which are marked Protected as part of a Managed Package, are visible to anyone who can customize setup in your Salesforce org. They are not intended for use as secure secret storage, **except** the aforementioned Protected Custom Metadata in a package. Such Protected settings might be used to store credentials but shouldn't be used to store credit card details.